# use different routes for different ports in express app

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible in express/node app to have different routes configured to different ports?
Example:
'/foo/bar' accessible to only localhost:3000
'/bar/foo' accessible to only localhost:3002

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you just create two servers, each on its own port and then create an express `app` object for each server and register routes for the desired server on the appropriate app object.  A given server only listens on one port.

```
const express = require('express');

// first server
const app3000 = express();
app3000.get('/bar/foo', function(req, res) {
    // code here for port 3000 handler
});
app3000.listen(3000);

// second server
const app3002 = express();
app3002.get('/foo/bar', function(req, res) {
    // code here for port 3002 handler
});
app3002.listen(3002);
```

Comment: I have tried this approach. The problem with this approach is that there are two separate apps and i can't share states stored in memory unless i use some sort of persistence that both app accesses.

Comment: @manish - That's not true.  You can easily share memory between these two server instances because they run in the same Javascript engine.  They both have access to the same variables (as I've defined them in the same module).  You can easily share module-level or global state between them by just using Javascript variables in this module.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00. What i was doing was running two different app in its own module separately. So, memory was not shared.

Comment: @manish - Even if they are in their own module, but still in the same node.js instance, then you can share anything the module chooses to share.